# Closed-form solution for 3D rotation angles given pre- and post-image

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, nonlinear-system

I'm working on some math involving a pinhole camera model, and I've run in to the following problem: given only $x$, $y$, $z$, $A$, $B$, and $C$, I need to solve for the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ in the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\phi & 0 & -\sin\phi \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sin\phi & 0 & \cos\phi \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta & 0 \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}
$$

under the assumption that $[x\ y\ z]^T$ and $[A\ B\ C]^T$ are both unit vectors.  I know that $\phi$ must be in the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$; the value of $\theta$ is unconstrained.

I am able to solve for $\theta$ and $\phi$ using Newton's method.  Is there a closed-form solution for $\theta$ and $\phi$ in this case, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I think we should convert the vectores from cartesian to the spherical coordinate system where the parameters are $r,\theta, \phi$. Then the matrices represent adding $\theta$ and then $\phi$ to the input vector. Have you tried this?

Comment: Can you include one sample data point so we can check the algo.

Comment: @SrinivasK I had not tried it, but your idea works very well.  Could you write it as a solution?  Thanks.

Comment: Actually,  I found out the solution is wrong. I'm trying to get the correct one. will post it soon.

Comment: @SrinivasK As you said, your method does not work.  For the test cases I have, it gave me angles very close to the correct ones, which is why I originally thought it worked.  See my comment on your answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions for each angle, only one of which will work best

$$\begin{aligned}
  \theta & = 2 \arctan\left( -\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-B^2}+x}{y+B}\right) \\
  \theta & = 2 \arctan\left( \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-B^2}-x}{y+B}\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
  \varphi & = 2 \arctan\left( -\frac{\sqrt{A^2+C^2-z^2}+A}{z+C}\right) \\
  \varphi & = 2 \arctan\left( \frac{\sqrt{A^2+C^2-z^2}-A}{z+C}\right) \\
\end{aligned}$$

### Why?

I used the [Tan Half Angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) substitution for $\theta = 2 \arctan(t)$ and $\varphi = 2 \arctan(s)$, $$\cos(\theta) = \frac{1-t^2}{t^2+1}$$ and $$\sin(\theta) = \frac{2 t}{t^2+1}$$ and similarly for $\cos(\varphi)$ and $\sin(\varphi)$.

Then I solved the two quadratic equations from the *y* and *z* components of the equation

$${\rm Rot}_Y(\varphi)[A,B,C] = {\rm Rot}_Z(-\theta) [x,y,z]$$

I used the standard convention for the 3×3 [rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) ${\rm Rot}_Y()$ and ${\rm Rot}_Z()$

The two equations I solved are

$$B = y \cos \theta-x \sin \theta \\ C \cos\varphi-A \sin\varphi=z$$

which get transformed to

$$ B = y \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-x \frac{2 t}{1+t^2} \\
   C \frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2} - A \frac{2 s}{1+s^2} = z $$

or

$$ B (1+t^2)=y (1-t^2)-2 t x \\ C (1-s^2) - 2 A s = z (1+s^2) $$

with solution
$$ t = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-B^2}-x}{y+B} \\ s = \frac{\sqrt{C^2+A^2-z^2}-A}{z+C} $$

Comment: Can you please explain the intuition behind the answer ? I'm finding it difficult to get the idea here.

Comment: You convert an equation with sines and cosines into a polynomial equation. It is a well known trick in robotics.

Comment: I've not read any books about robotics. But I'm interested in linear algebra in all all forms. So, can you please give me a reference where I can learn this stuff ? Thanks. My idea is that, the fisrt matrix rotates the vector parallel to $x-y$ plane by $\theta$ degree. So, we can convert to spherical coordinates and just increment the corresponding parameter by $\theta$. Then, we the second matrix rotates parallel to $x-z$ plane by $-\phi$. so, I will convert it to a modified spherical coordinates and increment the parameter by $\phi$. Then we need get it back to cartesian to get the answer.

Comment: Your equation is $[A,B,C] = RY(-\varphi) RZ(-\theta) [x,y,z]$. I rearranged it and considered only the last two components

Comment: I added more details to the solution.

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula?

Comment: I've never used them. Will read them . I think it'll take some time for me to do the calculations myself.

Comment: This solution produces the correct results.  In all of the test cases I tried, the second equation for each angle gave the desired result, and I was able to easily eliminate the other solution for $\phi$ since it was outside the valid range.

Comment: Funny how math works correctly sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this with what you get by direct computation. 
 
Step 1: Convert the vector $[x, y, z]$ into spherical coordinates as 
 $x=r\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)$
$y=r\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$
$z=r\cos(\alpha)$
Step 2: After applying the matrices we get the following vector which is equated to the given output 
$A=r\sin(\alpha+\theta)\cos(\beta-\phi)$
$B=r\sin(\alpha+\theta)\sin(\beta-\phi)$
$C=r\cos(\alpha+\theta)$
Now, convert the vector $[A,B,C]$ to the spherical coordinates and then the answer would hopefully become visible.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work.  The product of $[x\ y\ z]^T$ and the $\theta$-matrix is easily expressed in spherical coordinates, but the product of that result with the $\phi$-matrix is not.  You can see this by doing the matrix math using the spherical terms and applying trigonometric identities.  $A$, $B$, and $C$ cannot be expressed as simply as you have written.

Comment: I realized it and deleted the answer. But ja72 seems to have used somethings from here. That's why I kept the answer. So, you might use the answer given by ja72.